# How to display list data based on month in View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a view page where the user can select a year and based on the user selected year I want to display a list of records for each month. Something like below
[image]

But right now it is displaying as below

[image]

Below is my code

Index.cshtml

```
 <div >
            @{
                var year = DateTime.Now.Year;

                var years = DateTime.Now.Year - 5;
                for (var i = year; i > years; i--)
                {
                    var j = @i - 1;
                    <div class="col-md-1 ">
                        @Html.ActionLink(i.ToString(), "Index", new { i = i })
                    </div>
                }
            }
        </div>
    </div>
    @if (Model.Yearclick != 0)
    {
        <h2>@Model.Year</h2>
    }
    else
    {
        <h2>@year</h2>
    }
</div>
<div>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
            @foreach (var groupMonth in Model.Records.GroupBy(recordLists => new { recordLists.date.Value.Year, recordLists.date.Value.Month }))
            {
                <h3 class="Header"> @System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(groupMonth.Key.Month)</h3>
                foreach (var Record in groupMonth)
                {
                    <tr>
                        @Html.Partial("_ListPage", Record)
                    </tr>
                }
            }
    </table>
</div>
```

Partial View:

```
@model MacData.Models.Record

@{
ViewBag.Title = "View Records";
}
<td>
    @Model.l_name
</td>
<td>
    @Model.l_date
</td>
<td>
    @Html.ActionLink("Update", "Update") |
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete")
</td>
```

How to I get the list of records for each month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML table can only contain table rows, table headers, and a handful of other things, `h3` or other similar elements not included. So when you put `h3` as a direct child of `table`, it is rendered in a weird way.

Each month should be a row in the table too:

```
@foreach (var groupMonth in Model.Records.GroupBy(...))
{
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <div class="Header">
                Month name here
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>


    foreach (var Record in groupMonth)
    ...
}
```

Notice a single table cell with colspan - that merges three cells in a row into a single cell.